# What does "lightweight and serializable reference to an sObject" mean?

Tags: dynamic-apex

While reading documentation about [Dynamic Apex and Apex Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm), I found the definition of `token` which says:

> Token — a lightweight, **serializable reference** to an sObject or a field
>   that is validated at compile time. This is used for token describes.

What do both (1)`lightweight` and (2)`serializable reference` mean in this context?

From the documentation I can get some explanation for (1). But it just says why I would want to use `lightweight` tokens, and no word about what makes them lightweight

> Because tokens are lightweight, using them can make your code faster
>   and more efficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Lightweight

A full field describe can require hundreds or thousands of bytes in heap, while the token only requires something like 4 bytes.

## Serializable

You can't serialize DescribeFieldResult directly in many cases (e.g. batchable), but the tokens will go through without a problem.